# phpMyAdmin not editing correct row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In my phpMyAdmin, when using the built in interface to edit a field in a row, it will always default to an entirely different query in that row.

AS an example, I edit the row with an id of 5, setting the field "health" from 150 to 160, the query that returns is:

```
UPDATE `database.characters` SET `description`='' WHERE `id`=5
```

As you can guess, this is very frustrating, as not only has it not done what I've requested, but it's also cleared the description field. Each row in the database has a different behaviour, some will return no query at all, others will edit different fields and some will have no issue whatsoever.

If I construct the query myself everything is fine, but I have designers who want to edit using the interface.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `PHPmyadmin` is not PHP, it is just an interface to execute mysql commands. Are you using PHP? What is the query you have prior to execution? If you execute a select on that row what do you get?

Comment: Sounds like a job for PMA support rather than SO.